Why RAG is slower than LLM?
I used RAG with LLAMA3 for AI bot. I find RAG with chromadb is much slower than call LLM itself.
Following the test result, with just one simple web page about 1000 words, it takes more than 2 seconds for retrieving:
Time used for retrieving: 2.245511054992676
Time used for LLM: 2.1182022094726562

Here is my simple code:
embeddings = OllamaEmbeddings(model="llama3")
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=splits, embedding=embeddings)
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()
question = "What is COCONut?"
start = time.time()
retrieved_docs = retriever.invoke(question)
formatted_context = combine_docs(retrieved_docs)
end = time.time()
print(f"Time used for retrieving: {end - start}")

start = time.time()
answer = ollama_llm(question, formatted_context)
end = time.time()
print(f"Time used for LLM: {end - start}")

I found when my chromaDB size just about 1.4M, it takes more than 20 seconds for retrieving and still only takes about 3 or 4 seconds for LLM. Is there anything I missing? or RAG tech itself is so slow?


Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) models are slower as compared to Large Language Models (LLMs) due to an extra retrieval step.
Since RAG models search a database for relevant information, which can be time-consuming, especially with large databases, it is tend to be slower. Versus LLMs respond faster as they rely on pre-trained information and skip the said database retrieval step.
You must also note that LLMs may lack the most current or specific information compared to RAG models, which usually access external data sources and can provide more detailed responses using the latest information.
Thus, Despite being slower, RAG models have the advantage in response quality and relevance for complex, information-rich queries. Hope I am able to help.

Please mark this as a answer, if you think this sets a perfect context for your case.

Looks like I need to fine tuning LLAMA3, thanks for your answer!

Picture this: You're on a game show, and the host throws a curveball question your way. You've got two ways to tackle it:
Option 1: The Quick-Draw Approach (LLM Way)

You're like that kid in class who somehow memorized the entire
textbook. The moment you hear the question, bam! The answer's right
there on the tip of your tongue. It's fast, it's impressive, but it's
limited to what you've crammed into your brain.

Option 2: The Sidekick Strategy (RAG Way)

Now, imagine you've got this crazy-fast friend hiding just offstage.
When the host finishes the question, you give your buddy a quick
nudge. They dash off to this massive library, grab a bunch of relevant
books, skim through them at lightning speed, and whisper the juicy
bits back to you. You then mix this fresh info with your own smarts
and voila! You've got a killer answer. It takes a bit longer, sure,
but it's like having Google in your ear.

That's basically the difference between a regular AI and one using RAG. The RAG version might be a tad slower, but it's like comparing fast food to a home-cooked meal - sometimes it's worth the extra few minutes for something really satisfying.

RAG is slower than pure LLM, or fine tuned LLM as explained by @nbaua.
If you want faster responses in you custom data you need to fine tune the LLM, which makes it faster in response for custom use cases, but you need more machine power and beware of catastrophic forgetting.
Or check out other methods like PEFT(Parameter efficient fine tuning).
You can also try LLM-agentic approach which calls RAG based data only when necessary, this could be more adaptive solution.
Experiment with methods and choose wisely
